# Need to fetch table so that every row has Primary ID for key (ZEND)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

Need to fetch from database in that order so i can get key to be Primary Key of feched table (or any column from select that i point out).
Example

```
select id, name from account;
array(
  0 => array(id => 12345, name => Some Dude),
  1 => array(id => 12356, name => Other Dude)
)
```

And what i need is

```
array(
  12345 => array(id => 12345, name => Some Dude),
  12356 => array(id => 12356, name => Other Dude)
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not tied to Zend_Db_Table then you can use more direct approach and get more control over queries.

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select()->from('users',array('id', 'login'));  //SELECT id, login FROM users
$result = $db->fetchAssoc($select); //this is where magic happens
```

If you can get only array then you can transform it using this function:

```
/**
 * Transforms associative array to 'id'=>$column (or 'id'=>array(columns))
 * @param array $array - associative array
 * @param string|array $value - which column use as value (or array of columns)
 * @param string  - OPTIONAL which column use as key
 * @return type array - 
 */
function transformTable($array, $col, $key = 'id') {
    $tmp = array();

    if (is_array($col)) {
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            foreach ($col as $value) {
                $tmp[$item[$key]][$value] = $item[$value];
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $tmp[$item[$key]] = $item[$col];
        }
    }

    return $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch all the data from your table including ID's

```
$dbtbl = new Application_Model_DbTable_table(); //your table name
$var = $dbtbl->fetchAll($dbtbl->select());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Zend Dbtable. You just need to fetch the data from the table and 
loop throught it.

In your controller.

```
$myTable = new new Application_Model_DbTable_Account();    
$this->view->accounts = $myTable->fetchAll();

and in your html view 

just display it like this.

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id Nr.</th>
        <th>Name</th>       
    </tr>

<?php  foreach($this->accounts as $acc) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($acc->id);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escape($acc->name);?></td>             
    >/tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table
```

---